# +- before a square root in R

Tags: r, function, symbols

I'm trying to write an equation in R (see code below). I was wondering how I can correctly use **+-** before **sqrt()** in my code?

```
x <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
y <- %+-%sqrt((.5^2)-(x-.5)^2)+.5
```

Comment: Where is the operator `%+-%` defined?

Comment: see: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have the equation in parametric form, without requiring +- of sqrt.

```
theta <- seq(0,2*pi,0.01)
x <- 0.5 + 0.5*sin(theta)
y <- 0.5 + 0.5*cos(theta)
plot(x, y)
title(main= substitute(paste('x=(1+sin',theta,')/2, y=(1+cos', theta, ')/2')))
```

[image]

Try this:

```
draw.circle <- function(stepsize=.01) {
  theta <- seq(0,2*pi,by=stepsize) 
  x <- 0.5 + 0.5*sin(theta) 
  y <- 0.5 + 0.5*cos(theta) 
  plot(x, y,type="n",xlim = c(0,1),ylim = c(0,1)) 
  segments(x,y,.5,.5)
}

draw.circle(.01)
```

[image]

```
draw.circle(.02)
```

[image]

```
draw.circle(.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why the plot from your suggested sin() cos() looks like oval rather than a circle? Thanks

Comment: it's due to the size of the plot area, it's actually a circle (since the major and minor axis values are same, otherwise it would be an ellipse), you can try and find out. Updated the plot, you can also try, the advantage of this approach is that you don't need to think about +- part, the result will be exactly same'.

Comment: Oh, by the way, how can I change the radius of the circle?

Comment: Sure you need to change the constant 0.5, so in general it will be x = r + r*sin(theta), y = r + r*cos(theta), here r = 0.5, but we can have any r

Comment: Got you, so: I need some lines to go from the x, y (the edge of the circle) to the center of the circle (.5,.5) but I get way too many lines using (any suggestion?): seq(0,2*pi,by=.01)
x <- 0.5 + 0.5*sin(theta)
y <- 0.5 + 0.5*cos(theta)
plot(x, y,type="n",xlim = c(0,1),ylim = c(0,1))
segments(x,y,.5,.5)

Comment: Try theta <- seq(0,2*pi,by=.02) or by=0.03,..,0.05.

Comment: By the way it generates fractal-like figures, does it have any connection theoretically to the complex plane / julia / mandelbrot sets?

Comment: Oh no, this will just serve as a figure.

Answer (score 5):

Need to plot them separately but the `%+-%` operator can be used in plotmath expressions. Needs to be flanked by two values, however, hence the need to use the non-printing `phantom():`

```
x <- c( seq(0,1,by=0.01) )
y <- c( sqrt((.5^2)-(x-.5)^2)+.5, -sqrt((.5^2)-(x-.5)^2)+.5)
plot( rep(x,times=2), y)
title(main= bquote( phantom(0) %+-% sqrt((.5^2)-(x-.5)^2)+.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity,  how could I add "y ="  before the %+-%  in equation in the bquote command?                                                                                                 bquote( phantom(0) %+-% sqrt((.5^2)-(x-.5)^2)+.5))

Comment: Probably could be. I just like to make my expressions as pure-plotmath and avoid character values as much as I can. The exceptions are when it simplifies the expression greatly or when absolutely needed as with efforts to italicize digits.